# IronPython and Ahead-of-Time Compilation

Tags: python, clr, ironpython

While doing a breaf research on IronPython I got confused about it's execution model and how it integrates with C#.

Can you please point, which of these assumptions are wrong:

1. IronPython is Not compiled Ahead of time ( into a clr exe|dll
   with IL code)
2. IronPython is distributed as script
3. When executed, IronPython files are compiled at runtime into IL and then executed in a CLR AppDomain.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pyc.py` to create an exe/dll, but it's not well documented. Otherwise, you're basically right.

Comment: The pyc.py exe can be further optimized by building an installer and running NGEN on the DLL's during install.